# MSI installer: Adding multiple properties to SecureCustomProperties

Tags: windows, installation, windows-installer, delimiter

I'm looking for a way to add multiple properties to the `SecureCustomProperties` value in my .msi installer's property table.  I've tried comma delimiting, semi-colon delimiting, and even space delimiters.  None of the above seem to work.

Hints?

Answer (score 8):

Ok, so I was almost there ... **semi-colon delimited with NO SPACES**.  This appears to do the trick.

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: This solves the question mentioned above, but apparently I cannot accept my own answer as the solution (and so it remains "unsolved").

Comment: I think you can now mark your own answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Got my answer from

[msiexec does not pass parameters to custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176790/msiexec-does-not-pass-parameters-to-custom-action)

For me I needed to have the following:

```
msiexec.exe /i "App With Space.exe" /passive /norestart CustomProperty=AnyValueNoSpace CustomProperty2="Value With Space" CustomProperty3=A;List;Of;Values
```