# msiexec does not pass parameters from the command line

Tags: installation, windows-installer

I was trying to use MSI installer to install this file myInstaller.msi and also pass the value "192.168.2.1" to IPADDRESS, which is mandatory on the process of installation. However, it comes up an error message "install failed". I checked on Windows, the application is installed, but it's not on Windows Services, where it is supposed to be.

```
msiexec /i myInstaller.msi IPADDRESS=192.168.2.1
```

I also have read this link [msiexec does not pass parameters to custom action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176790/msiexec-does-not-pass-parameters-to-custom-action). There is comment saying that installing ORCA and then editing the MSI file, it should work, however, after I have deleted cut row containing CustomTextC_SetProperty_EDIT1, and then saved the MSI file, it seems it's broken, it can not even run, the file is damaged.

Any help for this? I have been working almost 2 days trying to work it out, but can't. :-(

Answer (score 1):

I'll try to answer with a **potential quick fix** rather than a long explanation:

- Open an unharmed copy of the MSI file with Orca
- Add to the Property table:

  - **Property column**: IPADDRESS **Value column**: 192.168.2.1
  - Then add IPADDRESS to the delimited list in **SecureCustomProperties**. See image below
- Save and close, and run the MSI

  - Open an elevated cmd.exe prompt (search in start menu for cmd.exe, right click and run as administrator)
  - Install with command line (modify with your own paths): **msiexec.exe /I "myInstaller.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log**"

Check results, and report here what you find. **Most likely there is something else wrong, but this will bypass most other error sources.**

I do not recommend this approach as anything but a quick test.

[image]

Comment: Hi Glytzhkof, thanks for your reply. My problem now is once I use Orca to modify the working MSI file and save it, it seems broken. It pops out a message "this installation package could not be opened. verify that the package exists and that you can access it, or contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package".

Comment: You can't get hold of a new copy of the file? Try running it silent with the command line above. This will bypass the GUI altogether and I am not sure if this will allow the setup to run even if there are errors in the user interface dialogs.